# jQuery Ajax jSon get sub array data

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

I'm trying to get jSon data from curl PHP.

Below is the jSon data getting from web.

[image]

I'm trying to get etd, note and value from sub json data.

I got error but I can't click the error in console. It show me blank.

```
$('#kurir').change(function()
{
    var asal = $('#asal').val();
    var kab = $('#kabupaten').val();
    var kurir = $('#kurir').val();
    var berat = $('#berat').val();

    $.ajax({
        type : 'POST',
        url : 'cek_ongkir.php',
        dataType: "JSON",
        data :  {'kab_id' : kab, 'kurir' : kurir, 'asal' : asal, 'berat' : berat},
        success: function (jsonStr) {
            $.each(jsonStr.rajaongkir.results,function(index,item){
                var len = item.costs.length;

                for(var i=0; i<len; i++)
                {
                    alert(item[i].cost.value);
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

How to do it?

UPDATED.
To make it more details, here below I add json data from web instead the screenshot.

Please have a look the data below.

```
{rajaongkir: {query: {origin: "48", destination: "61", weight: 3080, 

courier: "jne"},…}}
rajaongkir
:
{query: {origin: "48", destination: "61", weight: 3080, courier: "jne"},…}
destination_details
:
{city_id: "61", province_id: "12", province: "Kalimantan Barat", type: "Kabupaten",…}
origin_details
:
{city_id: "48", province_id: "17", province: "Kepulauan Riau", type: "Kota", city_name: "Batam",…}
query
:
{origin: "48", destination: "61", weight: 3080, courier: "jne"}
results
:
[{code: "jne", name: "Jalur Nugraha Ekakurir (JNE)", costs: [,…]}]
0
:
{code: "jne", name: "Jalur Nugraha Ekakurir (JNE)", costs: [,…]}
code
:
"jne"
costs
:
[,…]
0
:
{service: "OKE", description: "Ongkos Kirim Ekonomis", cost: [{value: 141000, etd: "5-7", note: ""}]}
cost
:
[{value: 141000, etd: "5-7", note: ""}]
0
:
{value: 141000, etd: "5-7", note: ""}
description
:
"Ongkos Kirim Ekonomis"
service
:
"OKE"
1
:
{service: "REG", description: "Layanan Reguler", cost: [{value: 165000, etd: "3-5", note: ""}]}
cost
:
[{value: 165000, etd: "3-5", note: ""}]
0
:
{value: 165000, etd: "3-5", note: ""}
description
:
"Layanan Reguler"
service
:
"REG"
name
:
"Jalur Nugraha Ekakurir (JNE)"
status
:
{code: 200, description: "OK"}
```

Comment: Can you please post and update the question the json object instead of a screenshot ?

Comment: Hi... updated my post